# "It" as placeholder

Tags: pronouns

Is it correct that :

1. I want it that he buy a new car.
2. It seems crazy that he got married second time.
3. Only in US is it possible that people want it.

Best regards,
Marek

Answer (score 1):

According to [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/placeholder),  a placeholder is:

> "An element of a sentence that is required by syntactic constraints
>   but carries little or no semantic information, for example the word *it*
>   as a subject in *it is a pity that she left*, where the true subject is
>   *that she left*."

Your first sentence has no placeholder when written correctly as:

"I want him to buy a new car."

In your second sentence "it" is a placeholder.  However, your sentence should be:

"It seems crazy that he got married **for a** second time." or "It seems crazy that he got married **again**."

Your third sentence is confusing as it uses "it" in two different ways. The second "it" shouldn't be used in a stand-alone sentence as no-one will know what that "it" refers to.

The sentence is better written as "Only in the US could people want purple cheese."

Answer (score -1):

1) Corrent: I want him to buy a new car. 
2) Ok
3) Correct: Such thing is only possible in US that people want it