# It/that is one of the most surprising things I've heard today - can we use "it" from the very beginning?

Tags: pronouns

Usually, people use "this" or "that" to refer to something and then use "it" to refer to that something.

What if we use "it" from the beginning instead of using "this" or "that" first.

Does that kind of usage imply "this" or "that" because of the clear context so that we can just use "it"?

**Example 1**

> A: I received a scholarship for the graduate program.

> B: **It** is one of the most surprising things I've heard today.

**Example 2**

> A: Oh my goodness. **It** is the newest shooter game. I want to buy it.

**Example 3**

> A: I received a scholarship for the graduate program.

> B: I will not call **it** an achievement to be proud of.

Comment: As long as your reader/listener is aware from the context what **it** refers to, yes, you can use it.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40792/it-as-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Pronouns usually require antecedents, so it<sup>1</sup> would be unusual to use "it" without knowing what it referred to.

In examples 1 and 3, "it" seems to refer to the entire preceding clause, so the pronoun "that" would work better.

In sentence 2, "it" could work if you were pointing directly at a game so that the listener could see it.

Note 1: This "it" does not require an antecedent because it is a dummy pronoun.

Comment: Thank you. So when something (a thing or an idea) is mentioned the first time, we use "this" or "that". And after that, no matter how often we refer to it, we only use "it", right? For example, I made two examples: (1) A: I received a scholarship for the graduate program. B: "That" is one of the most surprising things I've heard today. C: Congrats. I will tell "it" to our friends. D: "It" really motivated me. B: Yeah I couldn't believe "it" at first." (2) A: I received a scholarship. "That" is one of the surprising things today. I couldn't believe "it". However, "it" is something real.

Comment: No, the rules aren’t so strict. Some of your sentences are OK, but some have issues, and the comments aren’t really for extended discussions, so perhaps you could ask a new question about them?

Answer (score 1):

The use of "this," "that" and "it" is tricky - there's a post on it here that provides a brief introduction but doesn't cover the seemingly infinite nuances within the topic: [it VS. this Vs. that](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159475/it-vs-this-vs-that)

In examples 1 and 3, the use of "it" in B's responses is so unnatural that I'd go as far as to call it wrong. Use "that" instead, which is commonly used in spoken English to refer to something for the first time. (I could come up with a scenario in which "it" makes sense here, but that scenario is so remote that it's not worth getting into.)

In example 2, you could use any of these three words, depending on what you want to convey:

> Oh my goodness. This is the newest shooter game. I want to buy it.
> (Probably works best if you are physically close to the game or an
> image of the game.)
>
> Oh my goodness. That's the newest shooter game. I want to buy it.
> (You're probably farther away from the game.)
>
> Oh my goodness. It's the newest shooter game. I want to buy it. (Can
> work in either of the cases above, but conveys a stronger sense that you're just now
> noticing that the game is present or available.)

Notice that the "it" in the third example might be considered a "dummy," though I'll leave that terminological point to the grammar experts to sort out. In any case, it's the same sort of "it" that's used in "Oh my God, it's Marcia." You'd use that sentence to express surprise if, for example, you went to a party and noticed Marcia was there. You would obviously never otherwise use "it" to refer to a human being - i.e., you'd never say "I can't believe it came to the party."

Comment: Thank you. So when something (a thing or an idea) is mentioned the first time, we use "this" or "that". And after that, no matter how often we refer to it, we only use "it", right? For example, I made two examples: (1) A: I received a scholarship for the graduate program. B: "That" is one of the most surprising things I've heard today. C: Congrats. I will tell "it" to our friends. D: "It" really motivated me. B: Yeah I couldn't believe "it" at first." (2) A: I received a scholarship. "That" is one of the surprising things today. I couldn't believe "it". However, "it" is something real.

Comment: See, you're proving how complicated this all is. The rule you're suggesting makes sense generally and probably works a lot of the time, but one can easily construct a conversation that disproves it as an absolute rule. For example, I could imagine: "A: I got a scholarship. B: That's really cool! You should be really proud of that! C: Yeah, I agree, that's awesome. D: So, how much is it for?" In this case, to replace "that" with "it" in either B or C's lines would be non-idiomatic.